# Java Iterable<Iterable<T>> to ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>

Tags: java, generics, iterator

Maybe I am missing something but I thought that If I declare my class as such:

```
public class Something<T> implements Iterable<Iterable<T>> {
  public Something(Iterable<Iterable<T>> input) {
  ...
```

I should be able to instantiate it as such:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> l = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

Something<String> s = Something<String>(l);
```

Unfortunately this gimes me an error. I thought ArrayLists are Iterable so that should map exactly to my constructor definition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to modify your constructor to accept anything that extends `Iterable<T>`

```
public Something(Iterable<? extends Iterable<T>> list){}
```

The reason for this is because generic types cannot literally extend other generic types. A `List<String>` cannot be assigned to a `List<CharSequence>`. The keyword `extends` allows this type of assignment to occur.

Comment: Thanks, but now I am getting warnings here:

`public class Something<T> implements Iterable<Iterable<T>> {
 
 private Iterable<Iterable<T>> input;
 
 public Something(Iterable<? extends Iterable<T>> input) {
  this.input = (Iterable<Iterable<T>>)input;
 }`

Comment: I suggest find a copy of Effective Java by Josh Bloch and read up on "PECS". It will help you really understand what is going on. In any case, you need to have `Iterable<? extends Iterable<T>` everywhere you expect to assign `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`

Comment: or perhaps even `Iterable<? extends Iterable<? extends T>>`

Answer (score 1):

Subtyping with generics is very non-intuitive.  For what you want to do, you need wildcards, and it would be pretty ugly.

There's a great explanation here in Section 3 - http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf